# How to change the y axis of a 2D image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'd like to change the y-axis dimension of an image (2D np.array on python), like in this example.

[image]

I don't want to modify x-axis. Is there an easy way to do that on python, with openCV for example ?

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to distort the rows of pixels in a certain way?

Comment: yes it's what I want to do

Comment: Delete the arrow and draw a new one

Comment: use cv2.remap. You need to define the mapping in x (an identity mapping) and y (deformed as you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to non-linearly transform an image and keep the dimensions the
same you can use numpy array-indexing.

Method 1: using numpy array-indexing without any interpolation.  Causes visible quantization in the transformed image when the original space is stretched.

Method 2: using opencv remap, uses linear interpolation.  The interpolation hides the severe stretching of the original domain.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load in image
image = cv2.imread('face.jpg')
transform = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=image.dtype)

# non-linear transform
original_space = np.linspace(0, 1, image.shape[0])
new_space = original_space**2

# map the new space over the dimensions of the image
mapping = (new_space*(image.shape[0]-1)).astype(np.float32)

# method1 (no interpolation)
# transform[:, :] = image[mapping.astype(np.int), :]

# method2 (linear interpolation, a little better)
x, y = np.indices(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.float32)
x = np.repeat(mapping[np.newaxis].T, image.shape[1], axis=1)
transform = cv2.remap(image, y, x, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('transform', transform)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTThI.jpg

transformed image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlBfj.jpg

transform image using remap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmbIK.jpg

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to keep the same image dimensions. But I want to deform the y-axis. I want to apply a non-linear transformation to the y-axis, like in my exemple

Comment: @yoshi8585  I have made an edit, I think it is the transform you are looking for.

Comment: @yoshi8585 Added code utilizing the cv2.remap function, i.e. linear interpolation can be used.  Brought to my attention from Miki.  You really only see the difference in the stretched parts of the transformed image.